# how much is Metafont used these days?

Tags: metafont

Is it really all about TeX (and friends) these days, or does MetaFont still enjoy some use---even if that's in limited contexts?  It seems that for all intents and purposes, we're essentially at version `$e$` for MetaFont, while TeX may still get a few more digits before (regrettably) reaching `$\pi$`.

Comment: I have never used MF to make any fonts, but I still use it's more general purpose cousin, MetaPost, to create technical illustrations every day.

Comment: You may enjoy reading about the development of the Nara typeface: https://www.typotheque.com/articles/nara_-_the_typeface_that_never_existed

Comment: I should perhaps add that [this type of question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) runs a risk of getting closed on this site, because any answer is likely to be opinion based...

Comment: This could be regarded as a 'piece of string' question, but one might also argue that the relative number of questions here (and elsewhere) is a guide ... I would point to the fact that for use in PDFs, vector-based fonts are significantly advantageous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your supposition that metafont's current use is in "limited" or specialized contexts is borne out by the relatively recent *tugboat* articles that indicate in either the title or the synopsis in the ["annotated index"](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html) that metafont is a key component.

these articles are so listed:

[MFCONFIG: A Metafont plug-in module for the Freetype
 rasterizer](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-2/tb116choi.pdf),
Jaeyoung Choi, Sungmin Kim, Jojin Lee, and Geunho Jeong,
37:2 (2016), 163-170

[FreeType_MF_Module: A module for using Metafont directly inside the
 FreeType rasterizer](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-2/tb122choi-freetype.pdf),
Jaeyoung Choi, Ammar Ul Hassan, and Geunho Jeong,
39:2 (2018), 136-142

[FreeType_MF_Module2: Integration of Metafont, GF, and PK inside
 FreeType](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb40-2/tb125choi-freetype2.pdf),
Jaeyoung Choi, Saima Majeed, Ammar Ul Hassan, and Geunho Jeong,
40:2 (2019), 170-178

[Why didn't Metafont
 catch on?](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-3/tb93crossland.pdf),
Dave Crossland,
29:3 (2008), 418-420

[Corrections for slanted stems in Metafont and
 MetaPost](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-3/tb117romer.pdf),
Linus Romer,
37:3 (2016), 311-316

[Computer Modern Roman fonts for
 ebooks](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-3/tb117ruckert.pdf),
Martin Ruckert,
37:3 (2016), 277-280

[Writing Gregg Shorthand with Metafont and
 LaTeX](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-3/tb93sarman.pdf),
Stanislav Jan Šarman,
29:3 (2008), 458-461

[Writing Pitman shorthand with Metafont and
 LaTeX](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96sarman.pdf),
Stanislav Jan Šarman,
30:3 (2009), 107-111

[Meta-designing parameterized Arabic fonts for
 AlQalam](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-3/tb93sherif.pdf),
Ameer Sherif and Hossam Fahmy,
29:3 (2008), 435-443

[Parameterized Arabic font development for
 AlQalam](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91sherif.pdf),
Ameer Sherif and Hossam Fahmy,
29:1 (2008), 79-88

[Tsukurimashou: A Japanese-language font
 meta-family](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-3/tb108skala.pdf),
Matthew Skala,
34:3 (2013), 269-278

[Obyknovennaya Novaya (Ordinary New Face) in
 Metafont](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111solomykov.pdf),
Basil Solomykov,
35:3 (2014), 276

regarding your comment that metafont is "essentially at version $e$", knuth is still (on his own schedule) accepting bug reports for metafont, so it may well get some more digits.  additional digits for tex will only be bug fixes, so you could
say about tex that it is essentially at version $\pi$.

Comment: @Dan - While it's true that Knuth-TeX may not have been changing (and improving) all that much in recent years, that's not the whole story. The eTeX extensions were an important advance, as was pdfTeX. Plus, don't forget XeTeX and especially LuaTeX.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, there has already been a reported possible bug for metafont that is being held in the queue for his next review.  (granted, that's quite rare, but non-zero.)  i *know* that there are tex reports in the queue.  (and even "non-important" changes do add digits to the version number.)